# Zoom Effect Only Zooms Original Image Not New Image From Thumbnail

Tags: jquery, html, thumbnails, photo-gallery, zooming

**INFO**
I have a grid of div's. Each div opens a modal. Each modal has a simple thumbnail gallery (click thumbnail, main image is replaced).

**PROBLEM**
Zoom is only working with the original main image. It doesn't realize there is a new main image after clicking a thumbnail so it continues to zoom the original image.

**FIDDLE**
http://jsfiddle.net/zuhloobie/bcuh489d/2/

**QUESTION**
How do I alter the code so that it zooms the new main image chosen from the thumbnail?

**HTML**
`<div class="container">
        <div class="image wow rotateIn" data-wow-delay=".3s" data-wow-duration=".3s">
            <div id="gallery" class="zoom">
                <div class="content">
                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/900x900/000/fff" class="image_1">
                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/900x900/f00/fff" class="image_2" style="display:none">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="body wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay=".5s" data-wow-duration=".3s">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="thumb view2">
                    <a href="#" rel="2">
                        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/900x900/f00/fff" id="thumb_2" class="fit">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="thumb view2">
                    <a href="#" rel="1">
                        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/900x900/000/fff" id="thumb_1" class="fit">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`


**JQUERY**
`$('#gallery').simplegallery({
        galltime : 400, // transition delay
        gallcontent: '.content',
        gallthumbnail: '.thumbnail',
        gallthumb: '.thumb'
    });
$('.zoom').zoom({ on:'grab' });`


**PLUGINS USED**
[1] http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/
[2] http://www.jqueryscript.net/gallery/Minimalist-jQuery-Image-Gallery-with-Thumbnails.html

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you have is that the simplegallery is not aware of the zoom plugin that you are using.

The zoom plugin creates a new element with the first image that he finds based on the element you supply.

In order to make the zoom plugin change the image that you are zooming you need to make sure that image is updated to the one that you just clicked.

Add this code after you initialize the zoom plugin:

```
$('.thumb img').click(function() {
    $('.zoomImg').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

It should solve your problem.

Comment: Did you mean `$('.zoom img')`? With that correction it works, but I now have a new problem. Each new modal is populated with the previous modal's main image until I click a thumbnail. Example: Modal #1 has a main image and 2 thumbnails A and B. Modal #2 has a main image and 2 thumbnails C and D. I open Modal #1 and select thumb B which replaces the main image - I can also now zoom correctly (thank you). But when I close Modal #1 and open Modal #2, its main image is now thumb B from Modal #1 until I choose thumb C or D in Modal #2.

Comment: Same sort of problem if you did mean `$('.zoomImg')`. But this time, if I click Modal #1 and thumb B - it works and I can zoom. But if I close it and open Modal #2, and use the zoom function on the main image that is there, it zooms onto thumb B from Modal #1. Essentially, both comments of mine introduces the images from not being removed from memory. Each modal now remembers some instance of the last modal. Make sense?

Comment: The code is correct, no need to change anything. If you got problems with modals please provide a link with example of the problem.

Comment: Modal plugin: http://dixso.github.io/custombox/. Dev page: (look at first 2 boxes (city of boulder and dana)) - http://www.shynemedia.com/dev/sm/2015_site/portfolio/index.php

Comment: Your problem is that when you enter Modal#1 and click on the thumb, the hidden image (the one that shown upon zoom) is the image from Modal#1. Then - when you go to Modal#2, the hidden image is still the one from Modal#1 (so if you try to zoom you will zoom on the image from Modal#1), and only when you click on one of the thumbs on Modal#2 - the hidden image changes to your "correct" iamge. What you need to do is when the modal is Open - you need to make sure you change the source of the hidden image (`$('.zoomImg')`, check the second line in my answer) to the first image inside that modal.

Comment: I'm going to mark this answered, as you did answer my original question - thank you. If you don't mind - where do I change the source of the hidden image to your 2nd line?

Comment: I'm beginning to think that it is the thumbnail gallery causing the "memory" issue because it happens without zoom plugin enabled. Like if I choose the 3rd thumbnail in one modal, the next modal I open defaults to the 3rd thumbnail. If there is no 3rd thumbnail, it shows no image. How do I clear that each time it starts? I feel like I need code in the modal plugin so that the "past" is erased before starting a new modal session.